# Passport.js, express.js, redirect methods (successRedirect and failureRedirect)

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using express.js and passport.js.

This code is for login:

```
router
  .route('/login')

  .get((req, res) => res.render('pages/login'))

  .post((req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) return next(err)
      if (!user) return res.render('pages/login', { errMsg: info.message })
      req.login(user, err => {
        if (err) return next(err)
        return res.redirect('/')
      })
    })(req, res, next)
  })
```

What I need to understand now is how to use Passport.js redirect methods: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#redirects

How can I use this code in my own code?

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, solved like this

```
if (!user) return res.render('pages/login', { errMsg: info.message })  -->

if (!user) {
        req.flash('error', 'Invalid username or password');
        res.redirect('/login');
        return }

req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            // Invalid password
            if (err) {
                req.flash('error', 'Invalid username or password');
                next(err);
                return
            }
            req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
            res.redirect('/');
            return
        });
```

I didn't find another way of implementing successRedirect and failureRedirect, as you have to use the passport function .logIn